# How to package a Python application for distribution

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cythonize

I am trying to distribute a pretty complex proprietary  Python application to many Linux systems (that have no internet connection and that I don't control). So I want to reduce the dependency on the local system environment as much as possible.

I can use cython_freeze to convert the complete application into a a single Linux executable (that works).

But this executable still requires  all the Python packages (like reportlab, ...) used by the application to be installed (in the correct version) on the target system.

So my questions is, is there a way of doing the same thing with the external packages (ie find out what files to compile with cython (how?) and creating the main module (like cython_freeze)), or can I combine my cython_freeze created executable with PyInstaller (which will probably consist of hundreds of files) or what other alternatives are there?

Comment: Take in account that if it's propietary code it might go against some Linux distributions' rules which only contain open source code. Just check in which distributions you are installing the code before doing it.

Comment: Did you consider converting to single executable file with pyinstaller. it will include all dependencies. But I guess even as single directory option will work for you needs